# circuit buffer input with inverted bubble

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

The related question [Circuitikz inverter bubble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97644/circuitikz-inverter-bubble) shows how to invert an input on an AND gate. How can I do this on a buffer gate? (rightward facing triangle) I can't seem to find the documentation. I tried using the `node[buffer, inputs=i]` but it doesn't seem to recognize the `inputs` key.

---

Update: It looks like I can do it in a `tikzpicture` but not inside a `circuitikz` element. The following works, but I need to combine this and connect to some things in a `circuitikz` element:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
\node (a) [buffer gate, inputs=i] {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

**is there a way to use this inside a circuitikz drawing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possilbe solution is to define a buffer gate called `\buffergate` via `\newcommand` syntax that takes two arguments `#1=name` and `#2= rotation angle`. The proposed solutions redefine `not port` into `\buffergate`, so that buffer gate can be used inside a `circuitiz` drawing.  An example from `circuitikz` is borrowed and the proposals follow.

```
\newcommand{\buffergate}[2] 
{  % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
\begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate=#2]
\draw[thick] (#1) ++(-16pt,0) coordinate[ocirc,xshift=-2pt](#1in) -- ++(0,16pt) -- ++
(30pt,-16pt)coordinate(a) -- ++(-30pt,-16pt) -- cycle;
\draw (a) --++(6pt,0)coordinate(#1out);
\end{scope}
}
```

The logic behind is to call `not port`, color it with white, give it a label name, use the command `\bufergate`, as shown below.

```
\draw (1,0) node[not port,color=white,name=not1] () {};
\buffergate{not1}{0}  % 0 = horizontal
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\buffergate}[2] 
{  % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
\begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate=#2]
\draw[thick] (#1) ++(-16pt,0) coordinate[ocirc,xshift=-2pt](#1in) -- ++(0,16pt) -- ++(30pt,-16pt)coordinate(a) -- ++(-30pt,-16pt) -- cycle;
\draw (a) --++(6pt,0)coordinate(#1out);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}  

An example from circuitikz 

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw
(1,0) node[not port] (not1) {}
(3,0) node[not port] (not2) {}
(0,0) -- (not1.in)
(not2.in) -- (not1.out)
++(0,-1) node[ground] {} to [C] (not1.out)
(not2.out) -| (4,1) -| (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}


\medskip

Proposed solution 1 -- node 

\medskip

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw
(1,0) node[not port,color=white,name=not1] () {};
\buffergate{not1}{0}
\draw (3,0) node[not port,color=white,name=not2] () {};
\buffergate{not2}{-90}
\draw (0,0) -- (not1.in);
\draw(1.7,-1) node[ground] {} to [C] (not1out)
(not2out) -| (4,1) -| (0,0);
\draw (not1out) --++(0.5,0)|- (not2in);
\end{circuitikz}



\medskip

Proposed solution 2 -- path

\medskip

\begin{circuitikz} 
\path(0.5,0) to[not port,color=white,name=not1] (1.5,0);
\buffergate{not1}{0}
\path(2.5,0) to[not port,color=white,name=not2] (3.5,0);
\buffergate{not2}{90}
\draw (0,0) -- (not1in);
\draw (1.7,-1) node[ground] {} to [C] (not1out)
(not2out) -| (4,1) -| (0,0);
\draw (not1out) --++(0.5,0)|- (not2in);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```